# how to select a psoudo element (after) for change style in invalid and valid input

Tags: html, css, element

i add * after a input,
i want select this for change color in `input:valid` and `invalid`,
but by this CSS not working why?

```css
form::after {
    content: "*";
}

#fname:invalid~::after {
    background: red;
    border-color: yellow;
}

#fname:valid~::after {
    background: rgb(3, 183, 168);
    border-color: rgb(9, 9, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="/action_page.php" id="frm">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
        <input required type="text" id="fname" value=""><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) (supported in Firefox behind the layout.css.has-selector.enabled flag):

```css
#frm:after {
  content: "*";
}

#frm:has(#femail:invalid):after {
  background: red;
}

#frm:has(#femail:valid):after {
  background: rgb(3, 183, 168);
}
```

```html
<form action="?" id="frm">
  <label for="fname">Email:</label><br>
  <input required type="email" id="femail"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Or simply replace `:after` in `<form>` with, say, `<span>*</span>`:

```css
#femail:invalid ~ span {
  background: red;
}

#femail:valid ~ span {
  background: rgb(3, 183, 168);
}
```

```html
<form action="?" id="frm">
  <label for="fname">Email:</label><br>
  <input required type="email" id="femail"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <span>*</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `::after` with span

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" id="frm">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input required type="text" id="fname" value=""><br><br>
    <span>span</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```css
input:valid + span::after {
  content: "";
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Your code will not work. 1) `<br>` (not `<span>`) immediately follows `<input>` 2) `span::after` will not be displayed because it has `content: "";`